# What happens when die() is called within a function

Tags: php

I was working over a update profile page and have something like this to update user details:

**account.php**

```
include_once('update_account.php');
$verify_credentials = checkcredentials($email, $password);
if ($verify_credentials == 1)
{
  $update_result = updateaccount($email, $newpassword);
}
```

**update_account.php**

```
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');
function updateaccount($email, $newpassword)
{
    $actcode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
    $update_query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE TABLE fu_user SET email = '$email', password = '$newpassword', is_activated='0', activation_code='$actcode' where email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'") or die ('Unable to Update');
      if($update_query){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['activated'] = '0';
        $update_result = "Your Email and Password has been updated successfully.";
      }
return $update_result;
}
```

So now what will happen if the query failed to execute and `die()` is called? Will `updateaccount()` return anything to from where it is being called?

As per I know, `die()` is purely identical to `exit()` and halt the execution afterwards, and calls the destructors for its cleanup process.

Other way of performing above would be:

```
$update_query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE TABLE fu_user SET email = '$email', password = '$newpassword',
is_activated='0', activation_code='$actcode' where email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'");
if ($update_query)
{
    //Return Success
}
else
{
    //Return Failure
}
```

Comment: Instead of the hardcore die() you should go with Exceptions for error handling.

Comment: "*As per I know, die() is purely identical to exit() and halt the execution afterwards, and calls the destructor for its cleanup process.*" You answered your own question. Really though, all you have to do is give it a try and see for yourself. Run the script. If the page suddenly stops, `die()` was reached. If not, it wasn't.

Comment: BTW in your examples the `$update_query` contains just a string, you're not executing it actually. You should probably fix it.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Ah! I missed it somehow, updated now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Did my answer help you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider accepting it as an answer, it'll help others to find the answer more easily, other questions may be marked as a duplicate of this one then, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) or [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) end the script execution immediately. Nothing is returned from the function where `exit` is called because the execution simply doesn't continue in the normal flow.

As you wrote only [destructors are called](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) afterwards:

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

And one special case, you can also [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) which is called just before the execution is halted:

> Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or exit() is called.

As others pointed out, it's better idea to actually *handle the error state* than just halt the execution. I don't think you want to show a blank page with an error message to the user. Return a value which indicates the error state from the function or better use the [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and handle the error state on higher levels.

Answer (score 0):

> The die() is an inbuilt function in PHP. It is used to print the
>   message and exit from the current PHP script. It is equivalent to
>   exit() function in PHP.

**Syntax:**

```
die($message)
```

**Parameters:** This function accepts only one parameter and which is not mandatory to be passed.

**$message:** This parameter represents the message to printed while exiting from the script.
Return Value : It has no return value but prints given message while exiting the script.